# react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next warning thrown in Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am using `react-i18next` in my app to great effect but when I run the unit tests against my component:

```
const OptionList = ({
  definition,
  name,
  status = EMutationStatus.IDLE,
  onChange = () => null,
  value = [],
}: IOptionListProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { options } = definition;
  return (
    <Select
      name={name}
      data-testid="optionList"
      id={name}
      placeholder={t('COMMON.PLEASE_SELECT')}
      onChange={e => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)}
      defaultValue={value[0]}
      disabled={status === EMutationStatus.LOADING}
    >
      {options.map((option: string): React.ReactElement => {
        return (
          <option key={option} value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

It throws the following ***warning*** when running the unit test suite:

`react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next`

I am a bit lost as I have set up `react-i18next` for unit testing in a custom render function for `react-testing-library`.

My `i18n` instance for tests:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: 'cimode', // setting lng to 'cimode' will cause the t function to always return the key.
  // ----- ^
  // have a common namespace used around the full app
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations',

  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
  },

  resources: { en: { translations: {} }, zh: { translations: {} }, th: { translations: {} } },
});

export default i18n;
```

And my custom render function is as follows:

```
export function render(
  ui: RenderUI,
  { wrapper, ...options }: RenderOptions = {}
): RenderResult {
  if (!wrapper) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    wrapper = ({ children }) => (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ChakraProvider resetCSS theme={theme}>
          <QueryClientProvider client={testQueryClient}>
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>{children}</I18nextProvider>
          </QueryClientProvider>
        </ChakraProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }

  return defaultRender(ui, { wrapper, ...options });
}
```

It is only a warning so not a big deal but am confused as to why this is throwing here as I believe I have set up the Provider as outlined in the docs here:

https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

An anyone help me get rid of this warning?

## UPDATE

I tried adding the suggested jest mock of the `useTranslation` hook from the same testing link:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate hook can use it without a warning being shown
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str: string): string => str,
    };
  },
}));
```

But still I get the same warning.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me. You can find more info in the [official documentation](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing).

```js
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate hook can use it without a warning being shown
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 9):

Did you try to call `i18n.init()` inside beforeEach hook? And i18n should be the instance of your instantiated i18n instance.

The only difference that in my case I have named export of the i18n instance.

```
import { i18n } from "../../services/Internationalization";

describe('testSuite', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
    i18n.init();
  });
});
```

And in i18n.ts I have to do:

```
i18n.use(initReactI18Next).init(...some configs);
export { i18n };
```

Answer (score 1):

One modification for RyanP13s proposal,
I return an array as expected return value from `useTranslation()`, works now fine for me:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => {
    return [/* t */ (str: string): string => str, /* i18n */ { language: 'cimode' }]
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the warning is a mere one-liner in most setups:
**Simply include the module in which i18next is initialized into the [`setupFiles`-array in `jest.config.js`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array)**.

The discussion in this thread took things a bit further by contemplating creating a mock for the `useTranslation` hook, which seems unnecessary just to get rid of the warning. However, if you want a `jest.mock()` to be loaded before every test, the[`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)-array probably is the way to go.

---

For the sake of clarity, this is what my `jest.config.js` now looks like:

```js
const config = {
  rootDir: '../',
  preset: '@redwoodjs/testing/config/jest/web',
  setupFiles: ['web/src/i18n'],   // ← that was all, folks!
}

module.exports = config
```

NB: this is a RedwoodJS project and `web/src/i18n.js` is the file that includes the initialization module for i18next also used in the actual main `App.tsx`.

Comment: This worked for me. I thought for sure I'd also need to wrap my component under test in an i18n Provider or something, but I did not need to.

Answer (score 1):

What worked best for me (yet very similar to the update you posted) is to first do `jest.mock` for the `react-i18next` import and on the "global" `beforeEach` I mock the return value for `useTranslation`:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

jest.mock('react-i18next');

describe('OptionList', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        useTranslation.mockReturnValue({ t: key => key });
    });

    // your component tests here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `vitest` and the above answers did not work for me, also I refer to the `useTranslation` hook in order to extract the `t` function in my components or hooks.

The following solution is based on the updated [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing) of `react-i18next`.

This mock should prevent the warning message and allow your tests to run without any issues related to react-i18next.

### VITEST

```
vi.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate hook can use it without a warning being shown
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
  initReactI18next: {
    type: '3rdParty',
    init: () => {},
  },
}));
```

### JEST

```js
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate hook can use it without a warning being shown
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
  initReactI18next: {
    type: '3rdParty',
    init: () => {},
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the official solution, I found that creating an instance of i18n specifically for testing worked nicely. It renders the actual strings and you don't have to mock `useTranslation`, which is the usual recommendation.

Create a file called `i18nForTests`.

```js
// i18nForTests.js

import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import { fooTranslation } from '/translations/foo'
import { barTranslation } from '/translations/bar'

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'foo',
    fallbackLng: 'foo',
    ns: ['foobar'],
    defaultNS: 'foobar',
    debug: true,
    resources: {
      'foo': fooTranslation,
      'bar': barTranslation
    }
  })
  
 export default i18n
```

Then import and initialize this heinous hackery in `jest.setup.js`.

Note: if you don't have `jest.setup.js`, use this in whichever setup file you do have (see jest.config.js > `setupFiles`). If you don't have any setup files, create one.

```js
// jest.setup.js

import i18n from 'i18nForTests'

i18n.init()
```

Comment: How would you call the translations like this? On the test itself